# JSF компоненты не отображаются

Tags: intellij-idea, maven, jsf, wildfly, jboss

Использую IntelliJ Idea + JBoss WildFly + Maven.

В pom.xml добавил зависимости:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Создал файл page.xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">
<f:view>
    <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>
</f:view>
</html>
```

при запуске приложения, обычные html теги работают.
А вот компоненты JSF, вида `<h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/>` на странице не отображаются.

Вроде бы настроил всё правильно, подскажите в чем может быть проблема.
Спасибо

Comment: Скорее всего, проблема кроется где-то в "настроил **всё** правильно". Например, web.xml есть в приложении? Да и само веб-приложение есть? Вот неплохой пример Hello World на JSF: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-0-hello-world-example/ . Там в конце статьи можно скачать готовый проект. Начните с него, добейтесь чтобы работало, а дальше смотрите что не так в Вашем приложении. Или вообще, работайте дальше со скачанным проектом.

Comment: @bobzer Спасибо! полезная ссылочка